# Handling promises responses on Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have this functions:

```
function getCookies(response) {
    console.log(response)
    const raw = response.headers.raw()['set-cookie'];
    return raw.map((entry) => {
      const parts = entry.split(';');
      const cookiePart = parts[0];
      return cookiePart;
    }).join(';');
}

const _curl =  async ({method, URL, headers, body, redirectMode}) => {
    let options = {
        method: method,
        redirect: redirectMode,
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: headers
    }

    body ? Object.assign(options, {body: body}) : null
    return fetch(URL, ({...options}))
}
```

I'm sending requests to some sites and some I need to extract the response and cookies from the response.

```
(async() => {
    const getReferCredentials = await  // EXTRACT ONLY THE COOKIES FROM THE "SET-COOKIE" HEADER
    _curl({
            URL: "https://website.com/", 
            method: "GET",             
            headers:{
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36",
            }, 
            body: false, 
            redirectMode: "manual"
    })
    const referCookies = getCookies(getReferCredentials);
    cookies = referCookies

    const getOnePage = await // EXTRACT RESPONSE BODY AND COOKIES FROM HEADER SET-COOKIE
    _curl({
        URL: "https://website.com/one-page/", 
        method: "GET",         
        headers:{
            "coookie": cookies,
        }, 
        body: false, 
        redirectMode: "follow"
    }).then((res) => res.text()).then((result) =>  $ = cheerio.load(result)) 
  
    const token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');

    const checkoutCookies = getCookies(getOnePage ); // Error
    cookies = checkoutCookies 
});
```

The problem is in the `getOnePage` function, I'm not able to extract the cookies from the "SET-COOKIE" header at the same time I treat and declare the variable $ as an instance of the cheerio module. I can only extract cookies when I remove `then` blocks/treatments, as in the function `getReferCredentials`.

The only thing I need to be able to do is besides extract the cookies from the header, extract the html response from the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `.then()` method in an `async` function where `await` syntax is available. You're looking for

```
const getOnePage = await _curl({
    URL: "https://website.com/one-page/", 
    method: "GET",         
    headers:{
        "coookie": cookies,
    }, 
    body: false, 
    redirectMode: "follow"
});
const checkoutCookies = getCookies(getOnePage);

const result = await getOnePage.text();
const $ = cheerio.load(result);

…
```

This also fixes the missing declaration of the `$` variable.